# How can I prevent embedded applet from reloading after I reload jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I have applet embedded with jsp page.my problem is every time I refresh jsp page, applet also gets reloaded so Is there any way to prevent applet from reloading after I reload jsp page. I know there is client side -server side issues while doing this . But is there any way ?

Comment: You should probably keep the applet state in a user session and restore it after the applet is reloaded. Otherwise you can use AJAX to reload whatever part of the page you need and keep the applet intact.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... I suppose there is a way as to cache the applet (not to re-download it every web page refresh); I am not sure what applet start way do you use :S It is JNLP or...?

Anyway, I think you should look closer to [cache_option and cache_archive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet-caching.html) attributes

---

Report if that helped